# "Row_Number() over" wrong syntax

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have the following table structure

```
CREATE TABLE `Modular_LS` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`steamid` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
`name` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
`xp` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`prestige` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`creation_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

And this is the query I'm trying to execute:

```
SELECT rank, total 
FROM (
   SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY `prestige` DESC, `xp` DESC) AS rank, 
          ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Modular_LS) AS total, 
          steamid 
   FROM Modular_LS
) sub 
WHERE sub.steamid = '%s'
```

But I'm getting

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '(ORDER BY `prestige` DESC, `xp` DESC) AS rank, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Modular_LS)' at line 1
```

What am I doing wrong? This worked with a previous installation of MariaDB, but now it doesn't.

I'm also on v10.1.22 of MariaDB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MariaDB team introduced window functions (such as `ROW_NUMBER()`) as of version 10.2 and beyond.

You're working with 10.1.  Your previous installation must have been a later version.

Comment: Ah yes, should've researched more.